# Simple way to solve the product of a imaginary number's exponent:

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I came up with is to take the imaginary number's exponent, divide it by 2, and if it's positive then the answer is 1. If the result is odd then the answer is -1.

Example:

$i^8$

$8/2$

$4$

Since 4 is even the answer to $i^8$ is 1.

Comment: How would that work for $\,i^{-3}\,$, for example?

Comment: I think my formula doesn't really work :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let us stick to positive exponents for now:

Since $i^0 = 1$, work out $i^1, i^2, i^3$, and $i^4$, and then you will notice a pattern.

The answer to $i^4$ can be justified, since multiplying by $i$ is the same as rotating by $90º$ (in the counter-clockwise direction).

Comment: I see where my simple formula falls short. Every other result is a decimal and a decimal really can't be even or odd. On top of that sometimes the answer is just i.

Comment: @Samurai Thanks for the accept!